# Use ityped init with useRef and useEffect in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Trying to implement [ityped](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ityped#use-with-reactjs) in a React app. The code shown below should work in JSX; however, this React app is written in Typescript (TSX), which is why it fails with a type error.

**"Intro.tsx" component:**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { init } from 'ityped';
import "./intro.scss";

export default function Intro() {

    const textRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        init(textRef.current, { 
            showCursor: false, 
            strings: ['Web developer', 'Logo designer'] 
        })
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="intro" id="intro">
            <div className="left">
                <div className="imgContainer">
                    <img src="assets/man.png" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="right">
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <h2>Hi there, I'm</h2>
                    <h1>Andreas Petersen</h1>
                    <h3>A <span ref={textRef}></span> </h3>
                </div>
                <a href="#portfolio">
                    <img src="assets/down.png" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**The error is as follows:**
[image: Error Message]

My guess is that `const textRef = useRef(null);` needs to be defined in a way, so that `init()` from ityped can understand it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do two things. First, like you guessed, you'll need to specify what sort of ref this is:

```
const textRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);
```

Secondly, even with that type, `textRef.current` can still be null as far as the types are concerned. So you either need to add code to your use effect to check for null:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!textRef.current) {
    return;
  }
  init(textRef.current, { 
    showCursor: false, 
    strings: ['Web developer', 'Logo designer'] 
  })
}, []);
```

Or if you're confidant that you've made it impossible for it to be null after the first render (ie, you're unconditionally passing it into a component that will use it), you can use a non-null assertion (`!`) to insist to typescript that you know it's not null:

```
useEffect(() => {
  init(textRef.current!, { 
    showCursor: false, 
    strings: ['Web developer', 'Logo designer'] 
  })
}, []);
```

Be aware that this second option means you're telling typescript not to check your work. If you make a mistake and it actually can be null, typescript can't tell you that, and you may get unexpected behavior at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add type to your `useRef` so Typescript can understand that the ref is for a span element.

Try this: `const textRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);`

Comment: It gives me about the same error, but with a different argument type "Argument of type 'HTMLHeadingElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Element'."